# How to create a fast WPF Datagrid control from scratch?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, datagrid

I have been using a number of commercial WPF datagrids in the past and I must say the performance has been quite disappointing and slow. I would like to be able to load up up to a million records and be able to scroll up and down fast without any lag.

I have been told by some Guru WPF developers that it is indeed possible to create a WPF Datagrid from scratch - with far less features than the commercial ones - focused mainly on performance.

But how would I proceed? I have been told developing these datagrids should not be built in the usual way of utilizing the ItemsControl, which leads to the same performance problems as the existing wpf grids.

Is a Guru here to point me into the right direction?

**Update:**

Because one person mentioned the doubt of needing one million records, now too many are jumping on the same bandwagon.  What I am interested in is creating a low latency fast Datagrid with barely any feature, which can hold in theory up to a million record.

I dont require any sorting, filtering or else, all I need is speed. And thats where I needed guidance from a Guru.  I know what Data Virtualization is, its just not enough.

Comment: Your problem is not with the available controls, it is the million records. The right direction would be to build a USER interface.

Comment: Seriously, what is the point of having the ability to scroll fluently through a million entries if you cannot find anything because you are looking at *a million entries*?

Comment: @H.B. : The point is that plenty of WinForms DataGrids can do this fluently (and yes, scanning sorted list can be useful even with a million of entries)

Comment: How did you go? I also need a highly custom datagrid and I'm considering writing my own

Comment: @rolls It didn't go well.  Despite hiring expensive consultants and throwing many resources at it, WPF just wasn't cut for it.  We gave up eventually and implemented Winforms grids inside WPF controls. Ugly but functional and fast.

Comment: Was writing a custom GPU accelerated control not possible? Perhaps using unity or something along those lines.

Comment: You really think that's feasible?  It's better choosing an entirely different technology.  That was the main reason I switched away from .NET. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that you want to look at the VirtualisingStackPanel as part of your implementation, it only renders controls as they become visible.

However, a million records sounds like too many for any user to seriously need on screen at any one time. I'd seriously rethink my UI design but that's just me.

Comment: Datagrid Virtualization feature such as it's done in Infragistics etc is simply not performant enough.

Comment: Well do you know what aspects make it not performant? What's the bottle neck? Have you determined that it's definately the UI? Could it possibly be that getting 1million records from a database or accross a network might also be part of the problem?